# Algorithm for converting (coordinates + reach radius) data to directed graph

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, divide-and-conquer

I am trying to find a solution better than O(n<sup>2</sup>) for the following problem:

There are N points on a 2-D plane (N $\le$ 10<sup>6</sup>), with integer coordinates between -10<sup>5</sup> and 10<sup>5</sup>. Each point has an associated integer "reach radius" R<sub>i</sub> (0 < R<sub>i</sub> < 10<sup>5</sup>).

Build a directed graph (represented by adjacency lists) in which these points are the vertices and there is an edge from A to B if and only if point B falls in the reach of point A (i.e. euclidean_distance(A,B) $\le$ R<sub>A</sub>).

I am thinking of dividing the plane into 4 equal regions, and solving the same problem for the regions, but don't know how to combine the partial solutions...

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: Where does this problem come from? It looks a lot like a programming competition problem, for example. (If you only have a million points, a quadratic algorithm will almost certainly solve the problem overnight, for example.)

Comment: Yes this came to mind while trying to figure out a competition problem, which could be solved in linear time if I had the graph instead of the points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all pairs of points are within each other's reach, you can not optimize the construction below $O(N^2)$. However, you can optimize for sparser graphs by ordering pairs of points by distance from smallest distance to largest. Once you find a pair $(A, B)$ where $d(A, B) > R_{max}$, you are done. A technique you can use for this can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem#Dynamic_closest-pair_problem). This technique makes use of divide and conquer.

This is more a heuristic. I do not think there is a way (with or without use of divide and conquer) to reduce the worst case complexity.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the O(N^2) lower bound. I seem to have forgotten that there could be O(N^2) edges and then the whole struggle is kind of useless...